# Go: Sending gob's over a pipe is hanging - UPDATE: Out-of-process http.ResponseWriter is blocking

Tags: go, gob

I'm writing a webserver that distributes requests to out-of-process programs in Go. I'm sending the ResponseWriter and Request datatypes through Pipes using gob.

The problem is the external process is hanging when receiving the gob.

**UPDATE** The gob is now successfully being sent to the external process, but now the external process is blocking at `fmt.Fprintf(request.Resp, "Hello")` and freezes there.

dispreq.go

```
package dispreq

import (
    "net/http"
)

type DispReq struct {
    Resp    http.ResponseWriter
    Req *http.Request
}
```

dispatcher.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "dispreq"
)

func dispatch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    process := exec.Command("./hello")
    pipe, piperr := process.StdinPipe()

    if piperr != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, piperr.Error())
        return
    }

    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(pipe)

    process.Stdout = os.Stdout

    //UPDATE: encoder.Encode(&dispreq.DispReq{w, r})
    //UPDATE: process.Start()
    process.Start()
    encoder.Encode(&dispreq.DispReq{w, r})
    pipe.Close()
    process.Wait()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", dispatch)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

hello.go

```
package main

import (
    "dispreq"
    "encoding/gob"
    "os"

    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    gobDecoder := gob.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    var request dispreq.DispReq
    gobDecoder.Decode(&request)
    fmt.Fprintf(request.Resp, "Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start the process (`process.Start()`) before sending data to it (`encoder.Encode(&dispreq.DispReq{w, r})`). You might also need to flush your pipe by closing it (`pipe.Close()`) or sending a `\n`.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks.  But now I'm having a new problem where hello.go is blocking at fmt.Fprintf(request.Resp, "Hello").  Is it not possible to pass a ResponseWriter to a separate process?

Comment: That's because `encoding/gob` cannot encode file descriptors (the docs are [here](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob))